# How to hide a modal dialogbox in MFC application?

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog, hide

I have a hard time hiding a modal dialog box. What I am doing is - I am trying to design a UI for my own application in MFC, kind of a setup assistant.

In the 1st dialog box I have `NEXT` button, so when I click that it has to hide the 1st dialog box and move on to the 2nd dialog box, where I have some controls in 2nd dialog box.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to hide a Modal dialog...not sure how it can be done.

Anyway, it seems to me you don't need to hide the dialog but destroy the first one and create the second one. You can use [EndDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wddd3ztw(VS.80).aspx) to terminate a modal dialog.

But MFC has its own mechanism to create your own wizard, have a look at this class [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014(VS.80).aspx). I am sure you can find thousand of examples, [this is one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/simplepropertywizard.aspx).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should definitely use CPropertySheets

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ShowWindow()` function to hide modal
 Its default patametet is `SW_SHOW` which is equal true value 1 and
To hide modal use  `SW_HIDE` value when you click next button
You just use `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`   If you make prev button you should use modal pointer
Or next modal should child modal because you cannot have prev modal variable. 
I wish you understand me  for my english